# Copying cells to another sheet and inserting rows for the copied cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to create a sub that copies information from one form (which has four cells) to another sheet.

- When it copies the information it also creates a new row.
- Each form has a maximum of ten rows but it should be able to
  recognize when a form has empty cells and stop.
- It should also be easy to replicate to other forms.

A sample of the forms can be seen using the link below.

[image]

Here is my code which does not work

```
Sub Update_1()

Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = lastrow To 3
    Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Copy
    erow = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Sheet2.Cells(erow, 2)

    Sheet1.Cells(i, 2).Copy
    Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 1)

    Sheet1.Cells(i, 3).Copy
    Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 8)

    Sheet1.Cells(i, 4).Copy
    Sheet1.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(erow, 3)

    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Next i
End sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be better on stack overflow?

Comment: @rfportilla, if the focus of the question is do something in Excel, then it's fine here.

Comment: Why doesn't the code work? Does it give and error? If yes, what is it? Or does it just not give the results you expect?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `Selection.Insert` line?  Ultimately this code looks pretty good.  I see no glaring issues.  It's worth noting that `Copy` can take a `Destination` parameter which then allows you to delete the extra `Paste` line.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
Public Sub allergy_copy()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets(1)
    Set wks1 = wkb.Sheets(2)
    endrows = False
    thisrow = 3
    While endrows = False
        If wks.Cells(thisrow, 1) <> "" Then
            With wks
                .Rows(thisrow).Copy Destination:=wks1.Rows(thisrow)
                thisrow = thisrow + 1
            End With
        Else
            endrows = True
        End If
    Wend
End Sub
```